# Technical reason behind Mac OSX-formatted exFAT disk cannot be written in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macos, exfat

Read from this [discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4143858) and my current experience (annoyed by a USB drive), a USB drive formatted to exFAT in Mac OS X is unable to write in Windows 7. However, a disk formatted with exFAT in Windows 7 can be read & written in Mac OS X.

Why is this issue happen? Is the exFAT standard used in Mac different than in Windows 7? I seek for a technical reason for this issue.

*Note: I'm not asking for read-write solution (I can make an exFAT disk in Windows 7)*

Comment: The thread talks about sharing drives, not directly connecting them.

Comment: No, I have the same issue on my USB drive. Directly connected.

Comment: Does the raw header of the exFAT drive help?

Answer (score 1):

This is because OS X creates an EFI partition before the exFAT partition even on removable disks when using GPT. Windows only mounts the first partition on removable disks. In Windows 10, for some reason the exFAT partition shows as RAW under Disk Management when the EFI partition is present. If you use `diskpart` to delete the EFI partition, the exFAT partition will be detected correctly instead of showing up as RAW.